# How to trigger ItemAdd, from a class module, when I receive a message?

Tags: vba, outlook

I researched the ItemAdd event and created a class module that follows the example. My macro won't fire when I receive new messages.

The macro parses data within the email and saves it to an Excel file. It is in it's own module. I can run it manually.
I am trying to have it append new data each time I receive a new copy of the specific message.
I have a rule that forwards these emails into a special folder, Folder X, where I want the code to search for new messages.

My code in a class module.

```vb
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Initialize_handler()

    ' Reference the items in the Inbox. Because myOlItems is declared
    ' "WithEvents" the ItemAdd event will fire below.
    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder X").Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim myTitlePos As Integer
    Dim myTitleLen As Integer
    Dim myVarPos As Integer
    Dim myVarLen As Integer
    Dim strPrice As String
    Dim strYear As String
    Dim myVarCRLF As Integer
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim newLineTest As String 

    ' Check to make sure it is an Outlook mail message, otherwise
    ' subsequent code will probably fail depending on what type
    ' of item it is.
      
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

       'This is where all the working data parsing takes place.

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a sanity check here... have you created an instance of this class?

i.e. something like:

```
Dim c As MyClass
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    c = New MyClass
    ' If you don't rename Initialize_handler, you'll need:
    ' c.Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

in ThisOutlookSession...

I expect you'll also be wanting to change `Initialize_handler` to `Class_Initialize` unless you want to have to make an explicit call to it...

Comment: I need all the sanity checks I can get!  :)  Totally new to VBA.  Thus, I have not done that.  I tried to read up on instancing class modules, but hadn't quite wrapped my head around it yet.  I'll give that a shot.  Also, on the second point involving Intialize_handler, why the need for a name change?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  I have this currently in ThisOutlookSession: `Dim c As Object

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set c = New My_Class_Module
End Sub` On the second point on Intialize_handler, why the need for the name change?  I took that name from the Microsoft help example.  Thanks so much!

Comment: With it named `Class_Initialize` (which is what I MEANT to say!) it will be run when you write `... = New ...` (i.e. it is the default constructor), otherwise it won't be run unless you call it explicitly... a la `c.Initialize_handler`. I suspect that this is simply the problem, that that `Set myOlItems = ...` is never being run...

Comment: I made the changes you suggested above but it still doesn't seem to be working for some reason.  One thing I have noticed is that it does seem to be opening up the VBA editor every time I receive a new email message, even though these new messages are in my main inbox and now the private one created for the email of interest in this exercise.  It's not the end of the world if I can't get it to automatically run as I had hoped, since I can run it correctly manually, but it is confusing to me why I can't get it to run since it seems to be a straightforward exercise.

Comment: It doesn't look like the opening of the VBA editor with every new message part is true, but it does seem to open up somewhat randomly as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't see any reason that this wouldn't work... Is it opening up with an error? Or just opening up for fun? Have you tried putting breakpoints in to check what's going on? i.e. Check that myOLItems is getting set up properly, and checking that your ItemAdd code is being fired off? I'm a bit at loss otherwise I think.

Comment: Yeah I am too.  I'll do a bit more reading and try some debugging to figure it out, but I think it something I am missing on my end.  Luckily I have the other module to do the same work until I figure out how to automate it.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to have the routine initialize in ThisOutlookSession, Manage Rules & Alerts to Run a Script, where your script will be your routine.
-Redplaya